# Subset of dataframe, "not in index " error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have the following dataframe:

| Name | 1 -30 | Limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 1000 |
| B | 200 | 1000 |

I am trying to create a subset of this dataframe, for only the first two columns, with the following code:

Sub_DF = DF[["Name","1-30"]]

This unfortunately leads to the following error: KeyError: "['1-30'] not in index"

So my expected output should look like this:

| Name | 1 -30 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 200 |

I have tried using the iloc function but that did not help. I also tried to enter 1-30 without quotation marks.

Please find below the info about the column names:

- **Name**         243 non-null    object
- **1 -  30**      245 non-null    float64
- **Cred.limit**   213 non-null    float64

Any tips? Please note that I am new to programming :)

Comment: Looks like you have a space in `'1 -30'`. Can you provide the dataframe as dictionary (`df.to_dict()`)

Comment: Ah there was indeed an issue with the spaces! It does work now, thanks a lot!! Not really sure though what you meant with providing a dataframe as disctionary, what is the use of this function?

Comment: If the issue was the space and you no longer have an issue, this is no longer needed. Let me know and I'll close the question ;)

Comment: No worries! I just asked the second question out of curiousity/learning :) Yes that was indeed the issue and this question can be closed.

Comment: of course, the command was to provide us with a clean version of the dataframe to unambiguously see whether there was a space or not ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sub_DF = DF[["Name","1 -30"]]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).